# How to automatically send user data to mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use socket.io to broadcast geolocation (lat, lng) and set new marker icon on a map each time a user connects to the app. If a user in Japan connect, socket.io will send to me his position and he will receive my position too. Problem is that I don't want a user receive position of (and sent my position to) users that are far away, but only within a predefine radius (ex: 20 km).

Spatial search within mongo DB seems to be appropriate to identify users that are located in the same area and assign them to a groupId. Users of a same groupId would be allocated a common socket.io channel they will listen to.

To make my dream come true I'm actually trying to push user information into Mongo DB with mongoose. Problem is that mongoose run in the server while data are in the client.

I have define a schema.js to structure the database but I'm a little bit lost on how to setup the route to link client data with mongoose ? I understand that both mongoose and client must return the appropriate JSON object to communicate and data can be store with `model.save()`. Sorry for this naive question but help on that point would be appreciate a lot. Thank you.

**EDIT :**

I finally use socket.io to pass user data to the server with `send2DB` function but I'm facing this error :

```
Object { _id: 50fc08aebb97d3201d000001,
coords; [],
date: Sun Jan 20 2013 16:18:34 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid) } has no methode 'push'`
```

It seems to be a probelm with the array `coords` but I don't understand why it returns the date too! 
Here is the code :

**application.js :**

```
    // generate unique user id
    var userId = Math.random().toString(16).substring(2,15);

    // code here
    onLocationfound = function(e){
        userMarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
        map.setView(userMarker.getLatLng(),map.getZoom()); 
        latitude = (e.latlng[0]||( Math.round(e.latlng.lat*1000)/1000));
        longitude = (e.latlng[1]||( Math.round(e.latlng.lng*1000)/1000));

    // send data to database (executed once)
    sentData = {id: userId, coords: [{lat: latitude, lng: longitude}]}
    socket.emit('send2DB', sentData);
```

**server.js :**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// create schema
var userInformation = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    role: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    userId: String,
    longitude: Number,
    latitude: Number,
    coords: [Number, Number]
});

// export retrieve my model

var MyModel = mongoose.model('ModelName', userInformation);
var instance = new MyModel();

// code here

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

// code here

// Store user data to DB then query spatial info //
socket.on('send2DB', function (data) {

    console.log('Position is', data);
    instance.push(
        {userId: 'data.id'},
        {latitude: 'data.lat'}
        );
    instance.save(function (err) {
      if (!err) console.log('Success!')
      else console.log('Error');
    });

});
```

Comment: You'll need to write some code in the connection for socket.io to track specific users by using session or another token. Then as new data comes in, write a handler for the specific event with geo data on the server to update the location. You're just writing an API layer for your client application to call. The client won't (and shouldn't) call directly into the database.

Comment: I've updated my post with new code and result. To sumarize I try to store the data once location of the user is found. Then I'd query some spatial information in order to identify the users that are located around him. May you please have a look to the error I have ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're generally on the right path. Here are the few easily noted issues:

1. Where's the `push` method come from? (You don't have any arrays)
2. Don't you just want to set properties on a new instance of your MyModel when new data is received from the client?
3. I'd think you'd create a new MyModel when the socket retrieves the send2DB data. Then, just set the properties.
4. Also, you don't want to make the `userId` the quoted string `'data.id'`, do you? Don't you just want the value, just as `userId: data.id`?  (As you probably want the values from the socket `data` object)

The basics can be found in the mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html). .

```
socket.on('send2DB', function(data) {
    var instance = new MyModel({userId: data.id, latitude: data.lat});
    instance.save(function(err, instance) { /* callback */ });
});
```

Ultimately, you'd likely want to add some security and such to your API function and not just trust that the User.id is valid and the location.

Comment: Thank you WiredPrairie. 1. You're right `push` is not appropriate here. 2. It is exactly what I want. 3. I got it now. 4. That was my mistake. As you propose I create my model once `send2DB` is called. `if (!err) console.log('Success!') else console.log(instance);` show me that an error occurs and instance is undefined. Shall I add the security you mentioned with Express and socket.io session ? tx

Comment: @floflo Yes, I'd add the security with Express & socket.io.

Comment: What is the aim of adding instance callback in `function(err, instance)` ? because it reports no error without it, like this : `instance.save(function (err) {if (err) { console.log(err); } else console.log('Information added to the database');});`

Comment: If you're using a closure, it's not necessary. However, it is what the mongoose docs show, so I included it for completeness.

Comment: I have set userId with `index: {unique: true}` to avoid duplication of the user when his position change. I've been unable to manage that situation with `.update` neither with `$exists: true` and `.save` retruns an error. Anyway I'll try to review the code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe post a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Should be ok. i've written something nice with a couple of conditions to check if the user or his position has changed. Not bad :)